# adding FDT to the flash AS options

Tags: flash, fdt

How do I tell the flash Professional Creative Suite 6 to edit the Actionscript files in FDT instead of Flash Builder? Could I do this using a jsfl script? Using ANT?
[flash screen http://flashcamphawaii.com/flash_screen.png](http://flashcamphawaii.com/flash_screen.png)
![flash screen][1]

Basically I would like to add a option for "FDT"

Comment: I don't think it's possible :/ I'm assuming this b/c the App GUI would need to be updated to reflect this. You might be able to write a script to open a file in FDT; however, I don't think it would be available via this GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible :/ I'm assuming this b/c the App GUI would need to be updated to reflect this. You might be able to write a script to open a file in FDT; however, I don't think it would be available via this GUI.

(realized my previous comment should have been an answer)